# xna camera rotates around own axis and looks at model group

Tags: matrix, xna, camera

I made a 3D scene where I have three groups of models. I have a camera which is looking at one of those groups. 
Models in these groups rotate around the group center (Up axis), and models also rotate their own local center (Up axis).

This is similar to XNA Racing Game car selection screen. 
Only difference is that I want to be able to rotate my camera to look at another group.
When rotating camera to look at next group I want to rotate it 120 degrees (I have 3 model groups 360/3=120)

NOTE:
- camera is looking at a group from slightly above the group's plane.

for camera:

```
viewMatrix = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition, cameraTarget, Vector3.Up);    
projectionMatrix = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4, aspectRatio, 1f, 1000f);
```

OK:

- I can rotate model around its own axis.
- I can rotate group of models left or right around the group center point 
  (in game screen, closest model to the screen is the one currently selected).

Not OK:

- I cannot find correct way to rotate camera around it's own Up axis.

Couple of images to clarify this situation:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you want all your rotations to be about the world up axis rather than the camera's up axis.

here's a possible way to change the view from one group to another. This will rotate at a constant rate. If you want it the rotation to slow a little as it arrives at the desired group, addition code is required. This assumes you know the center position of each group.

```
float elapsed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
float rotationRate = 0.01f; //radians per second. set to taste
Vector3 cameraGoal;// the center point of the group that you want the camera to settle on. changes with input.

Vector3 currentLookingDirection = cameraTarget - cameraPosition;//
Vector3 desiredLookingDirection = cameraGoal - cameraPosition;
float angularSeparationFactor = Vector3.Dot(currentLookingDirection, desiredLookingDirection);
if(angularSeparationFactor < 0.98f);//set to taste
{
  float directionToRotate = Math.Sign(Vector3.Cross(currentLookingDirection , desiredLookingDirection ).Y);
   cameraTarget = Vector3.Transform(cameraTarget - cameraPosition, Matrix.CreateRotationY(rotationRate * elapsed * directionToRotate)) + cameraPosition;
}
else
{
   cameraTarget = cameraGoal;
}

view = Matrix.CreatLookAt(cameraPosition, cameraTarget, Vector3.Up);
```